# prompt changes color when I become a permanent superuser

Tags: prompt

I made my prompt more visible in the bashrc file but when I try to become a permanent superuser with sudo su - I get that horrible old blue on black, which is nearly impossible to see. How can I make the superuser prompt the same as the user prompt I set in bashrc?

Comment: change the bashrc for the root user?

Answer (score 2):

The same way you changed bashrc for your own user, root has a bashrc:

```
# pwd
/root
root@schijfwereld:~# ls -la
total 28
drwx------  4 root root 4096 aug 27 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 sep  4 19:58 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  549 okt 15 15:36 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3204 aug 27 20:55 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 jul 29 17:10 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 aug 27 20:55 .config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 aug 17  2015 .profile
```

Add your lines there and it will change your admin.